# jQueryMobile, Ajax Navigation, and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Following the MVC 4 article on new [Mobile Features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features), I added the NuGet package `jQuery.Mobile.MVC`.  That package installs, among other things, an older version 1.0.3b of jQuery Mobile (the current version is 1.1.0) and creates the following in `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml`:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function ()
{
    // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
    // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), hence disabling it.
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

I can not find any documentation on what exactly is not working, whether there is a bug filed for it, and what the status of that bug might be.  The closest non-ancient similar mention in the jQuery Mobile Forum is

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-navigation-system-is-causing-problems

In that case, the OP's issue was deemed "by design".

So...

Why might Ajax navigation be turned off out-of-the-box, and is that still a valid concern in jQuery Mobile 1.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem with MVC 4 Beta is that page navigation simply stops working after one navigation if the ajax navigation is not switched off.

This is still a valid concern in jQuery Mobile 1.1.0. I am using MVC 4 beta with jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, and navigation between pages is very unstable if the ajax navigation is not disabled.

*Note:*
The forum post you refer to is not related to this problem. The post is about values in the page header not being updated, which is per design.
<sub>(since this is the only problem for that OP, I guess he is using MVC 3)</sub>

---

About the status of this, related to your question:

> (...) whether there is a bug filed for it, and what the status of that bug might be (...)

I don't know... I am also anctious to know this. Hopefully, it will be fixed when MVC 4 is officially released.