# Re-displaying page after form submission in jquery mobile loses my attached events

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a multipage document but I've been displaying html and doing validation for a single page within one php file:

```
<div id="checkPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <?php
    $form = $_REQUEST['form'];  //this is simply a hidden input in my form that I reference to know if a form submission has occurred
    if($form) {
      $res = process();
      if(is_array($res)) { //if the data is an array then it is an array of errors that I will display to the user
        $html = page($res); 
      } else {
        $html = $res;  //if the data is not an array then it is confirmation html that the request was successful.
      }
    } else {
      $html = page();
    }
    echo $html;
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my page() function I am appending some jquery after my HTML:

```
$detail .= chr(10) . '<script type="text/javascript">';
$detail .= chr(10) . '$( "#checkPage" ).bind( "pageinit",function(event){';
$detail .= chr(10) . '  $("#txtAmount").change(function(){';
$detail .= chr(10) . '    alert("INSIDE");';
$detail .= chr(10) . '  });';
$detail .= chr(10) . '});';
$detail .= chr(10) . '</script>';
return $detail;
```

I see the alert when I navigate to my page then type-in (and leave) the amount textbox.  I also see the alert if I click the cancel button on the page (where I'm redirected to another page) then return again through menu hyperlinks and type-in (and leave) the textbox again. However, if I submit the form, discover validation errors and re-display the page, the pageinit is not set again.  Even if I leave off the pageinit logic the change event no longer is set.

What am I doing wrong?  I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Update:  If I add `data-ajax="false"` to my form then the change event seems to stick after a form submission.  But after my submission, if I click cancel (redirected to another page) and navigate back through a hyperlink it does not remember the event on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify the DOM, you actually get a whole new set of elements.  Events bound to elements that were replaced are gone, since the original DOM elements are no longer there.  See the jQuery FAQ

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F

You can use jQuery.live to bind to elements that match now and in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Or, you can place your binding logic in a common function and call it after Ajax success, as outlined here

http://jetlogs.org/2009/01/29/re-binding-jquery-events-on-ajax-callbacks/

Comment: If I change it from bind to live I have the same result.  The only difference is that the alert is displayed twice if I click cancel and return to the page again through menu links.  I don't really understand your ajax suggestion.  I just don't understand why the change event will not re-attach again.

Comment: After some playing I was able to use ajax to process.  It seems to remember the event as long as I don't include any pageinit stuff.  I place the html that is returned into my `<div data-role="content">`.  It looks terrible.  All the jquery mobile asthetics are gone.

Comment: I have run into the binding issue with standard jQuery (added a link to the jQuery FAQ on this in my answer), but disabled Ajax navigation in my jQuery Mobile app because it did not work correctly on all mobile devices that I care about.  Not 100% sure how the DOM re-creation and documented rebinding issue plays in a jQuery Mobile context.  Have you tried your code on a few devices / emulators?  jQuery Mobile Ajax Navigation does not work correctly on all devices.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232374/jquerymobile-ajax-navigation-and-mvc

Comment: +1 for `live` but [jQuery 1.7+ uses `$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked.  Eric J.  did get me on the right track.

```
$detail .= chr(10) . '<script type="text/javascript">';
$detail .= chr(10) . '$("#txtAmount").die("change");';
$detail .= chr(10) . '$( "#txtAmount" ).live( "change",function(event){';
$detail .= chr(10) . '  alert("CHANGE");';
$detail .= chr(10) . '});';
$detail .= chr(10) . '</script>';
```

Without the die then if I navigate away and come back it will be called multiple times.  But without live it will not work after form submission.